# Select records 7 days from today

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I am trying to select records where a field value (date) is 7 days from today, herefore I am using:

```
while select TableA where TableA.DateField == systemDateGet() +7
```

I am going to update some fields with the selected records, 1 of the fields keeps track if the record has been updated through this select statement.

If i would run this script today 26-09, it will select records with the DateField that has 03-10 as their value.

The problem is, if I wouldn't run this script today, but tomorrow, 03-10 will never be selected again, with the result the desired fields won't be updated.

What is the best way to solve this? Is their any way to select a date range for example?

Comment: What on earth is wrong with this question that it acquired 2 down-votes? +1 from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is their any way to select a date range for example?

Of course:

```
while select TableA
    where TableA.DateField <= systemDateGet() + 7
       && TableA.DateField >= systemDateGet() - 7
```

> 1 of the fields keeps track if the record has been updated through
>   this select statement

Something like this then?

```
while select TableA
    where TableA.DateField <= systemDateGet() + 7
       && TableA.HasBeenUpdated == NoYes::No
```